# Using RSA SecurID without a Windows Domain

Tags: security, domain, active-directory, rsa

I have a bunch of PCs I'd like to secure with RSA SecurID tokens.  However, they're not part of any Windows domain.  Is this doable? Anyone any experience with that?

Comment: Do you have the RSA server software or appliance already purchased and setup?

Answer (score 1):

This is doable.  There is no diffrence in the way you set up the agent at all.  Just make sure that you are using a non-DAC (Domain Authentication Client).  What you need us an RSA client that authenticates directly to the RSA server.  Once you have done this create an agent host for the computer and ensure the user has an account and token and your done.  The node secret will be created on first log in.  Also on a side note i have run into problems with having RSA store the windows password so i would uncheck that.  Oh one other thing be sure to check "Open to All Locally Known Users".  Reply here if you have any issues.